# Apple Configuration and invalid profile

Tags: wifi, appletv, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I am trying to configure Wi-Fi on an Apple TV 2 with WPA2 Enterprise.

The Apple TV asks for a profile so I am trying to configure one.

I set up the mandatory "General" settings

[image]

the certificate of the RADIUS server

[image]

And the Wi-Fi settings

[image]

[image]

When I install the profile or prepare the Apple TV via Apple Configurator (USB) I just get that the profile is *invalid*

[image]

How can I debug the problem? Is there a way to see a better error description or to validate the profile?

**Edit 1**

I tried as suggested with a minimal profile

- The required general infos
- WiFi with just the SSID (no security...)

I get the same error.

**Edit 2**

I enabled logging with

```
defaults write com.apple.configurator LogLevel ALL
```

after starting the "prepare" I get the error without any log entries. After clicking *Stop* I just get a single log entry

```
2016-02-18 15:47:53.177 com.apple.configurator.xpc.AirTrafficService[51010]: ERROR - 0ms - <ACUAirTrafficService: 0x7fca30d03420>: cannot call fetchOperationProgressForOperationID:reply: because: NSError: 0x7fca30d3eb60
Desc   : The operation is no longer available.
US Desc: The operation is no longer available.
Domain : ConfigurationUtilityKit.error
Code   : 0x65 (101)
 (ACUService.m:102)
```

**Edit 3**

I tried with "add profile" instead of prepare. In this case I am able to install a profile with the minimal Wi-Fi profile.

As soon as I enable WPA2 Enterprise it fails.

Comment: Are you using Apple Configurator v2 to prepare and install the certificate?

Comment: I am using Apple Configurator 2

Comment: What do you mean by "prepare" the certificate? I exported the certificate of our RADIUS server from my Key Chain.

Comment: @klanomath how? I just have the possibility to set the time zone settings to automatic or manual. In both cases I cannot connect to the network

Comment: @Matteo hmm I suspect that the current (arbitrary) ∂ time (ATV time - Radius server) may be too big (>300 seconds).

Comment: @klanomath Could be but I don't find a way to set the time on the ATV manually

Comment: @Matteo I have no ATV at hand so I can guess only. But it should be possible by attaching the ATV via ethernet and sharing your Mac's Wi-Fi -> Ethernet. After waiting some time the ATV time should be updated...

Comment: @klanomath For ethernet I have the same problem: it requires authentication

Comment: @Matteo If you share your Mac's network connection to the Apple TV device it shouldn't require an authentication

Comment: @klanomath I could try but it would not solve my original problem: connect the Apple TV to a WPA2 Enterprise network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35920/discussion-between-klanomath-and-matteo).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are trying to apply a setting that isn't supported on the AppleTV 2.  I'd start with the typical troubleshooting of start simple and then add more.

So, create the profile with **only** the General section configured and apply it.  If that works, move on to another section.  Repeat until it stops working.

Some items to look into are

- The encryption of the certificate.  If it is the wrong size or type, it might not be supported on the ATV2.  The device probably can't support the latest encryption methods.
- Perhaps the PEAP authentication protocol you have selected in the WiFi section isn't supported, so try TLS.

Good luck.

Comment: A profile with the general section only will not be applied "This profile contains no payloads and cannot be installed on devices"

Comment: I tried to create a profile with the certificate only (minimal payload) but it not usable "This profile does not contain a Wi-Fi payload"

Comment: Try just the WiFi section but don't add the trust info (so you won't need the certificate).  Keep it simple and it doesn't actually have to match what your WiFi network requires (yet).  You are just testing if you can delivery any profile at all.

Comment: Same error even with a minimal Wi-Fi configuration (see above)